# Resume chronometer after back pressed

Tags: android, chronometer

In my android project i have an activity A which contains chronometer and a button to start it, a button to stop it, a button to pause it and everything is working fine. Now the problem is when i press the back button on my activity then chronometer time does not resume from the same state when i come back to that activity.
I've tried many things many codes but nothing seems to work at all
Mchronometrer.setbase(Mchronometer.getbase()b-SystemClock.elapsedRealTime());
Any suggestions or codes would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the state of your activity. Check [this:](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating).
To save your state use this:

```
private static final String CURRENT_TIME="current_time";
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the current time in millis

    savedInstanceState.putLong(CURRENT_TIME, your_time_from_chronometer);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and to restore the state

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the time from saved 
    mCurrentTime = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_TIME);
}
```

It still depends in what format you have your time saved but a good options is using time in millis.

Comment: Code would be helpful

Comment: @raviraghav ok i made an edit